# Error: invalid magic number. Unaligned pointer 0xbf4c2c08

Tags: release-freya, system-installation

Well, I've been trying to install elementary OS Freya 0.3, but I've been having some issues.

I downloaded the 64-bit version from `www.elementary.io`, and used unetbootin, to make my pen-drive `bootable`, but when I boot and press install, the following message appears -

```
Error: invalid magic number. Unaligned pointer 0xbf4c2c08
```

I downloaded a dozen of times and also tried to use Rufus 2.2, but it doesn't even boot. Can someone help me?

Comment: Are your BIOS using UDMA? If yes, try to disable it.

Comment: Make sure that your pen drive is formatted to FAT32. I had some similar issues.